# How to change placeholders for antd range picker component

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, components, antd, daterangepicker

Unlike date picker, range picker of antd has two place holders defaulted to Start Date, End Date

[image]

I want to change the placeholders to Start, End.

I have tried the following code which doesn't work as expected

```
<RangePicker placeholder={"start,end"} />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### You can pass placeholder as an array of strings for Range Picker

If you are planning to change both the placeholders of the Range Picker, you need to pass them as an array of strings as below.

```
<RangePicker placeholder={["Start", "End"]} />
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change colour of place holder?